# MediaRecorder large video file size

Tags: java, android, android-mediarecorder

I'm using `MediaRecorder` to capture my device's screen and audio.

Here is the related code snippet:

```
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(128000);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(path + "/" + fileName + ".mp4");
mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mScreenWidth, mScreenHeight);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(5 * mScreenWidth * mScreenHeight);
mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(60);

try {
    mediaRecorder.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "createMediaRecorder: e = " + e.toString());
}
```

The problem is that the file size is way too big.

I tried the following to reduce the file size:

- Disable audio recording by removing:

  ```
   mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
   mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(128000);
   mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
   mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
  ```
- Reducing `setVideoEncodingBitRate` to `1000000` as stated in the docs. If I change it to even less then the video becomes "choppy".
- Reducing `setVideoFrameRate` to 30, this reduces the size somewhat.

How can I reduce the output file size while maintaining a decent quality?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I am having the same problem.